Will an additional air filter in the air return damage the motor?
The AC (located on the lower level) has a filter in front of the motor.  Will a second air filter put in the air return to reduce the air flow noise on the upper floor damage the motor?

Have you confirmed that the filter reduces air flow noise? It might make more if the airspeed is high enough.

It will not damage the motor,
you will get less air flow, less cooling/heating.
